# Determine whether the set S (below) is a subspace of $M_2(\mathbb{R})$ (The space f all 2x2 matrices with real entities)

Tags: linear-algebra

$$S = \left\{
\begin{pmatrix}
2a && -b \\
3b && a
\end{pmatrix}\;:\;\; a,b \in \Bbb R\right\}$$

So, I have to find that it is either closed under addition and scalar multiplication, I asked a similar question to this earlier today but made a mistake with how I asked it, so apologies for that. However I am still left with a few difficulties in the proving that is/isn't a subspace of $M_2(\mathbb{R})$

Also, can a set S be a subspace of $M_2(\mathbb{R})$ at all? Or does it fail  from the beginning?

Comment: Now it does not fail from the beginning. How did you try to verify it is a subspace?

Comment: treating x as a and y as b for sake of notation, am I along the right lines for addition?$$\begin{align}
\begin{pmatrix}
2x_1 && -y_1\\
3y_1 && x_1
\end{pmatrix}
&+
\begin{pmatrix}
2x_2 && -y_2\\
3y_2 && x_2
\end{pmatrix}
=
\\&
\begin{pmatrix}
(2x_1 + 2x_2) && (-y_1 - y_2)\\
(3y_1+ 3y_2) && (x_1 + x_2)
\end{pmatrix}
\end{align}$$

Comment: Do you think the result is in S?

Comment: Yes, I believe so, the result also lies in S. Just to confirm, is what I have tried above correct thus far? (Sorry for slower replies, I'm trying to get hold of this as we progress)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your way to show that S is closed under addition is absolutely correct but it is better to continue like this : 
$\begin{bmatrix}(2x_1+2x_2) & (-y_1-y_2)\\(3y_1+3y_2) & (x_1+x_2)\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}2(x_1+x_2) & -(y_1+y_2)\\3(y_1+y_2) & (x_1+x_2)\end{bmatrix}\in S$ since $(x_1+x_2),(y_1+y_2)\in R$ 
I think you can handle multiplication as well.

Comment: Thank you for all the help!

Comment: you can check as an answer if it was useful

Answer (score 0):

In the comments it seems like you've shown that S is closed under addition, since after you've added the matrices together you get another matrix that belongs to $S$ with $a=x_1+x_2$, $b=y_1+y_2$.  The subtle point is that if $x_1,x_2\in\mathbb{R}$, then their sum is also a real number, and the same for the $y_1,y_2$.

The only thing left is scalar multiplication, which is to say if $T\in S$ then $c*T\in S$ for all $c\in\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: Also, for multiplication:

$$
r\begin{pmatrix}
2a && -b\\
3b && a
\end{pmatrix}
=
\begin{pmatrix}
r(2a) && -rb\\
r(3b) && ra
\end{pmatrix}
$$

Since a,b,r $\in$ $R$ It is closed by scalar Multiplication. Since if a and b are real, under scalar multiplication of another real number r, the product would also be real.

I don't think I would be wrong in saying I need to refine this, but I think I am along the right lines

Answer (score 0):

The $2\times2$ real matrices form a vector space under matrix addition and multiplication by scalars. Each one of your matrices can be written as
$$
a\begin{pmatrix}2 & 0 \\ 0 & 1\end{pmatrix}+
b\begin{pmatrix}0 & -1 \\ 3 & 0\end{pmatrix}
$$
so $S$ is the set of all linear combinations of the two matrices
$$
\begin{pmatrix}2 & 0 \\ 0 & 1\end{pmatrix},\qquad
\begin{pmatrix}0 & -1 \\ 3 & 0\end{pmatrix}
$$
and as such it is a vector subspace of $M_2(\mathbb{R})$.